# keyup search function to also take input value

Tags: javascript, jquery, function

I have the following keyup search function, which works when a user enters information directly into this field. See below:

```
    if(this.$search_ele.length){
      this.has_search = true;
      this.searchFn = this.buildSearchFn(opts.fields);
      this.bindEvent(opts.ele, 'keyup' );
    }
```

I have now built an additional function, where if a user selects a button, the button information is then populated into the search. See below:

```
  function searchInput(num) { 
      var txt=document.getElementById("searchbox").value; 
      txt=txt + num; 
      document.getElementById("searchbox").value=txt; 
      }
```

Triggered by the following:

```
<input type="button" value="<%= name %>" name="no" onclick="searchInput(this.value)">
```

I am now trying to update my search function to also take this value, as it obviously wont work as anticipated because there is no direct user input (keyup or keydown). Trouble is, I am struggling with using the correct approach for adding in this new search feature.

I have read that I can assign multiple events by using a space, but I don't think this is correct?

```
 if(this.$search_ele.length){
      this.has_search = true;
      this.searchFn = this.buildSearchFn(opts.fields);
      this.bindEvent(opts.ele, 'keyup change' );
    }
```

Building out the statement to accept another bindEvent is also not correct

```
 else if(this.$search_ele.length){
      this.has_search = true;
      this.searchFn = this.buildSearchFn(opts.fields);
      this.bindEvent(opts.ele, 'change' );
    }
```

Suggestions on where I am going wrong?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: hi, interesting, perhaps the `focusout` event or `focus` might also be useful

Comment: Thank you jspcal - I will read into the mdn for this.

Comment: I think I am getting somewhere with the focus option. Where the search is now working IF I then click into the populated searchbox. Looking at updating my function now so when the button is pressed, the input box is then focused.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for steering me in the right direction jspcal with the focus tip!

I have now updated my code, and is working as intended.

```
function searchInput(num) { 
      var txt=document.getElementById("searchbox").value; 
      txt=txt + num; 
      document.getElementById("searchbox").value=txt; 
      document.getElementById("searchbox").focus();
      }
```

AND...

```
 if(this.$search_ele.length){
      this.has_search = true;
      this.searchFn = this.buildSearchFn(opts.fields);
      this.bindEvent(opts.ele, 'keyup focus' );
    }
```

Thank you again.